# Webpack добавляет не нужный файл в общий chunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

Всем привет, у меня есть проект React + Typescript + react-app-rewired

У проекта есть дополнительная папка SDK в которой хранятся файлы .js, .wasm, .simd.wasm, .data
Файл SDK/sdk.js уже оптимизированный и минифицированный.

В компоненте я могу использовать импорт

```js
import {Foo} from '../public/SDK/sdk.js';
```

Но бандлер закидывает SDK/sdk.js в чанк (`3.[hash].chunk.js`). Нужно сделать так, чтобы бандлер вообще не трогал папку SDK и просто положил его рядом в папку build. Потому что при `yarn build` и запуске этой папки, приложение ломается, жалуясь на `n.setVolume is not a function`

**Ожидаемое поеведение**

```
 - build
   - sdk (Не тронутые файлы)
   - static (только чанки нужные для работы реакта)
   - ...другие
```

**Текущее поведение**

```
 - build
   - sdk (Не тронутые файлы)
   - static (реакт чанки в перемешку с переоптимизированным и переминифицированным js из SDK/sdk.js)
   - ...другие
```

**tsconfig.json**

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "outDir": "build",
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "public/sdk", "build", "public/**/*.js", "src/**/*.js"],
}
```

**config-overrides.js**

```js
const { removeModuleScopePlugin } = require('customize-cra');

module.exports = removeModuleScopePlugin();
```

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Comment: Поменял @aleksandrbarakin

Comment: В массив в аргументе конструктора `CopyWebpackPlugin` добавь объект `{ from: 'public/SDK/*', to: 'build/sdk/' }`. Конечно же, copy-webpack-plugin должен быть добавлен в зависимости и в конфиг вебпака. Если с путями неок, скорректируй по ситуации. Возможно потребуется еще и исключить файлы в опциях лоадеров (по идее не должно потребоваться, т.к. плагины сначала, а лоадеры по эмиту... но всякое бывает).